# 2., 3. und 4. Äpfel oder 2, 3 und 4 Äpfel

Tags: numbers

Ein Deutschlerner seiend, habe ich kürzlich gelernt, dass man einen Punkt nach jeder Ordinalzahl in Deutsch setzen soll. Jetzt habe ich eine Frage für euch: Wenn es einige Ordinalzahlen in dem Satz gibt, soll man einen Punkt nach jeder setzen?

Zum Beispiel: Meine Fledermaus zu mir flog, und sie sagte: "Ich hatte vier Äpfel. Der **[1./1]** Apfel wurde von mir persönlich gefressen, und die **[2., 3. und 4./2, 3 und 4]** Äpfel wurden von meinen Freundinnen rasch verschlungen, weil sie hungrig waren.

Comment: Ein Deutschlerner seiend klingt etwas unnatürlich. Besser ist es zu sagen "Als Deutschlernender".

Answer (score 6):

Ja, es muss ein Punkt nach jeder Ordinalzahl gesetzt werden, weil der Satz sonst missverständlich ist.

Der Satz "Die 2, 3 und 4 Äpfel wurden verschlungen" könnte so verstanden werden, dass einmal von 2, dann von 3 und schließlich von 4 Äpfeln die Rede ist, insgesamt also von 9 Äpfeln.

Korrekt ist: "Der 2., 3. und 4. Apfel wurden verschlungen". Nomen und Artikel müssen im Singular stehen, denn bei jedem Element der Aufzählung handelt es sich um einen Apfel.

Comment: "weil der Satz sonst missverständlich ist" - ich würde sogar soweit gehen, zu behaupten, dass im Deuschen eine Zahl ohne Punkt dahinter gar keine Ordinalzahl ist, sondern einfach eine Kardinalzahl. Und damit ändert sich einfach die Bedeutung des Satzes (sofern er überhaupt noch grammatikalisch sinnvoll ist).